# How android CameraManager knows list of equipped camera

Tags: android, android-camera2, hal

Each smartphone possesses different camera device set.
For example, Galaxy S21 and Galaxy S9 possess different camera devices. Moreover, they have different number of cameras.

I am wondering how `CameraManager.getCameraIdList` in Android can tell us the result with considering the running device.
Does Android have some algorithm to detect equipped camera in runtime? or do smartphone manufacturers describe camera information with constant variables when they implement HAL interface?

Answer (score 1):

OS has direct access to Hardware and it provide System Camera Service that enumerates all Camera Interfaces. All those information are held in that Service as "cache" and provides them when CameraAPI needs them. If an external Camera is connected/founded that Service updates its internal "cache" for further Camera API requests.
The "ID" is just an Identifier for pointing-to-a-specific item in that "cache".